# Which region should be shaded?

Tags: inequality, education

I'm not quite sure which region should be shaded. Is there anyone who can confirm the if the answer is correct?

Find the range of values of x  which satisfies this inequality?

```
 (2x+1)(5-3x) < 0
```

I calculated the inequality as this is my answer

```
 x < -1/2  and x < 5/3

 -1/2 < x < 5/3  which means the region between -1/2 and 5/3 should be shaded ?
```

Comment: It's actually the complement of the region you have found (the parabola is open downwards)... but yes, that would be the region to be shaded

Comment: You switch from `x < -1/2` to `-1/2 < x`. Which one do yo mean?

Comment: @TonyK I just believe when the inequality is less than 0, then the range would be in this form n1<x<n2. Whereas when the inequality is greater than 0, the range would be x> n1 and x<n2.... I am confused whether to use x < -1/2 or x>-1/2...?

Comment: So you used both, which is _guaranteeed_ to be wrong :-)

Comment: You should have learned that the regions of interest are $(-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}),~(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{3}),~(\frac{5}{3},\infty)$.  Now, you can plug in a test point for each region to see how the *entire* region acts.  A convenient test point for the first region might be something like $-1000000000$, some obscenely negative number such that you can fudge the arithmetic.  For the second region, $0$ is conveniently located inside of it and is also easy to work with.  Then it is a matter of deciding how the boundaries of the regions act as well, which should be quick to do.

Answer (score 1):

From your inequality you immediately see that the zeros of the function $f(x) = (2x+1)(5-3x) = -6x^2+7x + 5$ are
$$x_1 = -\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad x_2= \frac{3}{5}.$$
The function $f$ is a quadratic function. In your case it's a convex parabola (headed downwards). The function hence has to take negative values for $x$ outside the interval $\left[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{5}\right]$. Therefore the solutions $x$ of your inequality belong to the set
$$\Bbb{L}=]-\infty, -\frac12 [ \,\, \cup \,\, ]\frac35, + \infty[.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have $x > \frac{5}{3}$ instead (try it with $x=2$ for example), so the region to be shaded is actually $x < -\frac{1}{2}$ and $x > \frac{5}{3}$.

In general, once you have the factored form, you can make a sign diagram to find the shaded region:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{sign of $f(x)$} & - & + & - \\
\hline
x & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{5}{3} \\
\end{array}
$$

You can also notice that the parabola has a negative $x^2$ coefficient, so the parabola is concave down, from which you can get to the same conclusion.

Using a graphing tool such as [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/puxsnmxjnq) or Wolfram Alpha will give you the answer if you are really not sure, but not how to find the answer (unless you have WA Pro).